# Python pyinstaller Permission Denied while unpacking

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller

I'm getting a permission denied error when trying to unpack pyinstaller. Is there anything specific about this line? I've tried to look up add-ons I need. I have pip, PyWin32, and PYODBC.

I ran the command `pip install PyInstaller` and at first it looked good, then I got:

> error: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   'build\lib\Pyinstaller\utils\git.py'
>
> Cleaning up... //...Storing debug log for failure in
>   C:\Users\gc\pip\pip.log

Here's what the log has:

> InstallationError: Command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import
>   setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='c:\users\gc\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_gc\pyinstaller\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record
>   c:\users\gc\appdata\local\temp\pip-3xxb4l-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in c:\users\gc\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_gc\pyinstaller

Comment: I use it all the time ... I have never `pip installed pyinstaller` just download the bundle extract it to anywhere you want and call it directly ... `~/pyinstaller_installed_folder/pyinstaller.py --onefile my_main.py`

Comment: Oops, realized your on Windows. Open an administrator command prompt and try the command again.

Comment: Thanks IronManMark20, I feel a little silly for not thinking to try that.